# how to wrote 'SUM' or 'function' or 'MOY' that can feet any line

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of value to wrote on different sheet of a spreadsheet;

the code look like that :

```
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const SHEET_TO_GET = ['BOURGET', 'ALPINES MUSEUM DAV', 'BLOIS_MAQUETTE', 'BELVEDERE MUSEUM', 'BELVEDERE MUSEUM'];
  const DATA_TO_WRITE = [['2D', "MAREIKE", '50', '33.0'],
  ['PROJECT MANAGEMENT', "LOUISE", '50', '16.5'],
  ['PROJECT MANAGEMENT', "MAREIKE", '50', '6.0'],
  ['FABRICATION', "MAREIKE", '50', '6.0'],
  ['2D', "MAREIKE", '50', '31.5']];
  SHEET_TO_GET.forEach((n, i) => {
    let sh = sss.getSheetByName(n);
    let col1 = sh.getRange("A1:A" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
    let nr = col1.indexOf("MATERIAL") + 1;
    sh.insertRowBefore(nr);
    sh.getRange(nr, 1, 1, DATA_TO_WRITE[i].length ).setValues([DATA_TO_WRITE[i]]);
  });
```

but in a perfect world, I would like to wrote one more information, a "value" that will make a sum of the column C*D (in the column E) for each row where a value is wrote, no matter the row where it is wrote.

here is the value :

```
DATA_TO_WRITE = [['2D', "MAREIKE", '50', '33.0'],
  ['PROJECT MANAGEMENT', "LOUISE", '50', '16.5'],
  ['PROJECT MANAGEMENT', "MAREIKE", '50', '6.0'],
  ['FABRICATION', "MAREIKE", '50', '6.0'],
  ['2D', "MAREIKE", '50', '31.5']];
```

and I would like to know if there is anyway to wrote something like that :

```
const DATA_TO_WRITE = [['2D', "MAREIKE", '50', '33.0', "=SUM(C*D)"],
  ['PROJECT MANAGEMENT', "LOUISE", '50', '16.5', "=SUM(C*D)"],
  ['PROJECT MANAGEMENT', "MAREIKE", '50', '6.0', "=SUM(C*D)"],
  ['FABRICATION', "MAREIKE", '50', '6.0', "=SUM(C*D)"],
  ['2D', "MAREIKE", '50', '31.5', "=SUM(C*D)"]];
```

Or do I have to think about something more complicated ?

here what the code produce :
[image]

here is my wish :
[image]

Comment: When I saw your `here is my wish :`, it seemed that you wanted to put the value of "C3 * D3" into "E3" and put the value of "C4 * D4" into "E4". But, it seems that you say `a "value" that will make a sum of the column C*D (in the column E) for each row where a value is wrote` and you want to use a formula of `=SUM(C*D)`. So, unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the details of your question?

Comment: For example, if you want to put the value of "C3 * D3" into "E3", how about modifying `sh.getRange(nr, 1, 1, DATA_TO_WRITE[i].length ).setValues([DATA_TO_WRITE[i]]);` to `sh.getRange(nr, 1, 1, DATA_TO_WRITE[i].length + 1).setValues([[...DATA_TO_WRITE[i], DATA_TO_WRITE[i][2] * DATA_TO_WRITE[i][3]]]);`? But, I cannot still correctly understand your expected result. So, if this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: What does `or 'MOY' that can feet any line` mean?

Comment: thx ! I already have an anwser that will do the job ! But I have to apologize for my english skill who doesn't seems to allow me to give you the perfect explanation that I need !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myfunck() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ns = ['Sheet0', 'ALPINES MUSEUM DAV', 'BLOIS_MAQUETTE', 'BELVEDERE MUSEUM', 'BELVEDERE MUSEUM'];
  let vs = [['2D', "MAREIKE", '50', '33.0'],
  ['PROJECT MANAGEMENT', "LOUISE", '50', '16.5'],
  ['PROJECT MANAGEMENT', "MAREIKE", '50', '6.0'],
  ['FABRICATION', "MAREIKE", '50', '6.0'],
  ['2D', "MAREIKE", '50', '31.5']];
  vs = vs.map(([a,b,c,d]) => {[a,b,c,d,parseFloat(c) * parseFloat(d)]});
  ns.forEach((n, i) => {
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName(n);
    let col1 = sh.getRange("A1:A" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
    let nr = col1.indexOf("MATERIAL") + 1;
    sh.insertRowBefore(nr);
    sh.getRange(nr, 1, 1, vs[i].length ).setValues([vs[i]]);
  });
}
```